# Which should I choose Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 or Windows Server 2003 x32?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, .net

I’m a .net 2.0 developer. We have an application which is running on windows 2003. Right now we have to set up new build machine. I’m wondering, should we use windows 2003 x32 still, or maybe we should use windows 2008 R2 x64?

We are using on development machines Windows 7 x64. I think it’s not a risk to use Windows 2008 R2 x64 as a build machine and Windows 2003 as a staging and test machines.

What is your opinion in above topic?

Do anybody have any lint to the Microsoft site where is told when does the support for Windows 2003 expire? I mean when do they assumes to finish support of Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mainstream Support on Windows 2003 R2 Expired this year in July and it's currently in Extended Support Phase (until 07/2015)

You can always check on: 
http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/

Answer (score 2):

For build and infrasturcutre I would go modern. Any testing is another thing, but tha can safely be done within a virtual machien in msot cases.

So, go 2008 R2. A build machine is not there to test app compatibility, but to build (and run unit tests). No sense in building this with an old / outdated platform. Easpecially 32 bit - will limit you a LOT in memory, which may be an issue. 64 bit at least can easily address more memory (even if the processes you run a 32 bit). Comes in handy for some build processes / setups which may require a lot of stuff done in parallel.

Comment: One thing to be sure and note is that when you configure this build machine and test your app take detailed notes if there are any configuration changes you need to make your application compatible. If not, when you eventually move your test, staging and production servers to 2008 R@ you will be retracing the same ground.